# Zoho Catalyst : facing "CORS error" when I try to access my Catalyst application which is embedded as an iFrame in another application

Tags: zoho

I have a web application hosted in Zoho Catalyst. I have a client URL for this application provided by Catalyst. When I embedded my Catalyst application as a iFrame in Zoho CRM/any third party application. I am facing the bellow error in the browser console

Access to fetch at 'https://mytestproject.catalystserverless.com/app/index.html' from origin 'https://crm.zoho.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I resolve this error in order to embed my application in a third party application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to embed your Catalyst application as an iFrame in some other third party applications, you need to add the calling parent domain under the Authorized domains in the Catalyst console.

Navigate to your [Catalyst console](https://console.catalyst.zoho.com) -> Authentication Service -> Click on the Authorised domains -> Add your parent domain from which you are trying to load your Catalyst application. Enable CORS and iFrame for the domain. Now you will be able to successfully embed your application in the other third party domains.

Example: If your catalyst app domain is https://mytestproject.catalystserverless.com/app/index.html and you are trying to load it as a WebTab in Zoho CRM (crm.zoho.com). Then, you need to add the domain crm.zoho.com and enable CORS & iFrame under the Authorised domains in the Catalyst console. This was mentioned in their help documentation page [here](https://catalyst.zoho.com/help/authorized-domains.html#Configure_Domain).

Hope this helps!